# classification of simple nuclear $C^*$-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Can we classify the simple nuclear $C^*$-algebras completely? Can anyone recommend some papers or books concerning the calssification of nuclear $C^*$-algebras

Comment: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540423058

Comment: It would help people to judge what sources to recommend if you said more about what you have studied/researched so far in the world of Cstar algebras. The classification programme has become very technical and there are known counterexamples to some of the original hopes for classification.

Comment: I think a slightly better question would be to ask for resources to help someone at beginner level learn about what the classification programme is, some of the history, some of the basic results, and so on. Papers at the frontiers of the classification programme will not necessarily be written with beginners in mind

Comment: @Yemon Choi， I wonder whether the simple nuclear $C^*$-algebeas have been classified completely till now.

Comment: As I said in a comment on an answer to one of your previous questions: the answer is that the Elliott invariant is insufficient unless one imposes some extra restrictions. My point was that you need to learn about Cstar algebras before learning about the classification programme, and your question gives no indication of what previous background you already have